# How to turn equation tags off by default?

Tags: math-mode, equations, starred-version

I'm writing a document in which very few of the equations actually need tags. So instead of using starred environments, I would much prefer to exchange the meaning of the starred with the non-starred environments. I don't mind if I need to specify each environment for which I want this done, so that I would have something like the following in my preable:

```
\makeatletter
%some TEX-fu magic that defines \exchangest@renv goes here
\exchangest@renv{equation}
\exchangest@renv{align}
\exchangest@renv{gather}
\exchangest@renv{alignat} %this might be a hard one as it takes an agument!
\makeatother
```

and then when using `\begin{equation}` I'd get the non-starred version, while the starred version `\begin{equation*}` would have a tag.

---

PS. Not sure what tags I should use for this....

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you could use [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4728/1235) instead.

Comment: This works in a pinch (for now), but if I want to turn on the tag without ref'ing the equation, I'm not sure how to do that (I could use phantom and clap or something crazy I guess) but a starred version for showing tags would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\newIF{%
  \count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
    \let\ifst@rred\iffalse
    \def\st@rredtrue{\let\ifst@rred\iffalse}
    \def\st@rredfalse{\let\ifst@rred\iftrue}
  \escapechar\count@}
\def\ChangeStar{\newIF
 \renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswfalse
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
 }{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
 }
 \renewenvironment{equation*}{%
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswtrue
  \mathdisplay{equation*}%
 }{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation*}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
 }}
\def\OldStar{\newif\ifst@rred
  \renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \incr@eqnum
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
  \mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\renewenvironment{equation*}{%
  \mathdisplay@push
  \st@rredtrue \global\@eqnswfalse
  \mathdisplay{equation*}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplay{equation*}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}}
\makeatother


\ChangeStar
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 y=x
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
 y=x
\end{equation*}

\begin{align}
 y=x
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
 y=x
\end{align*}

\OldStar

\begin{align}
 y=x
\end{align}


\begin{align*}
 y=x
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Herbert: Works for align, but not for equation..

Comment: why do you need the equation environment? align does it all

Comment: I changed the code. On the a quick view I do not see an easy solution, because equation is handled diffrent to the align environments.

Comment: wowsers....I didn't expect this...OK I guess I'm asking for some serious under-the-hood operation....

Comment: @Herbert, could there not be a way to do an \g@add@to@env is a similar way to the nifty \g@add@to@macro ? and then to the equation* env you add a  \incr@eqnum and to the equation* you add a \let\incr@eqnum\relax...would that work?

Comment: @Herbert...I never though about not needing the equation env....I always atartoff with equation...then change it to align if I need more capacity...the force of habit I guess...I'll force myself to change now....thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As Hendrik suggested in the comments, you can use `mathtools` with `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}` to mark the equations you actually reference. For additional equations that you want to be numbered, but don't want to reference, you use `\noeqref`. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:asdf}
adsf
\end{equation}
\noeqref{eq:asdf}
\end{document}
```

This requires minimal extra work, but make sure you read the `mathtools` documentation carefully to make sure you understand the interaction this has with `amsmath`.