# Suppress equation number when not refered to

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

Is is possible to use only `equation` or `align` environments without the `*` and then automatically suppress the equation number if there is nothing refering to that equation? It would make the LaTeX-life much easier I think.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/how-do-i-number-equations-only-if-they-are-referred-to-in-the-text

Answer (score 13, accepted):

see package `mathtools` and section "3.2.2 Showing only referenced tags". You'll get the documentation by running `texdoc mathtools` or run `texdoctk` if you run Linux

Answer (score 3):

I coded up a workaround before I noticed Herbert's answer.  Here it is anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
% TEX.SE \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15820/1402}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto{\equation}{%
  \notag
  \preto{\label}{%
    \refstepcounter{equation}
    \tag{\arabic{equation}}%
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
A = A
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{B}
B = B
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
C = C
\end{equation}

Proof: See Equation~\ref{B}.

\end{document}
```

It's my first use of the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) macros to prepend and append code to hooks.  This method first appends `\notag` to every equation beginning, thus suppressing equation numbering; then prepends to `\label` the code which steps the counter and resets the tag.