# Selective equation numbering in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I number equations only if they are referred to in the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/how-do-i-number-equations-only-if-they-are-referred-to-in-the-text)

I would like to number only the equations I actually refer in a manuscript. I know plenty of ways to do this manually, but as the manuscript progresses and I change which equations I refer to later I am likely to forget to change the display style of those equations.

I would really like a way to make latex automatically recognize that an equations is being referred and typeset all equations not referred unnumbered, and typeset all equations that are referred using `\ref{}` with numbers in the right margin.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
```

Awkwardly, as pointed out in the comments, this only works if each equation is referenced at least once with `\eqref`. (As long as there is one `\eqref`, other `\ref`s to the same equation will work.

Comment: Please note this may have a sideeffect: Sadly this turns of the proximity detection system within the amsmath environments. In other works the equation will act as if there is no equation number with regard to horizontal positioning of the equation. There is currently no solution to this problem.

Comment: (Originally a proposed edit by user7295) You might also have to use `\eqref` instead of `\ref`.