# Turn off numbering on unused equations

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, amsmath, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I number equations only if they are referred to in the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/how-do-i-number-equations-only-if-they-are-referred-to-in-the-text)

While I am writing a document, I like to use `align` rather than `align*` and `label` them for all equations that I write in case I need to refer to them later in the document. I end up not referencing some of the equations I have `label`ed. I was wondering if there is an easy way to strip equation numbers for equations that are not called using `eqref` anywhere in the document?

I can imagine this can be a difficult task where LaTeX will have to keep a list of `label`s and a list of `eqref`s and then unless the document is changed between compilations, "un-number" the ones in its list of `label`s that are not found in the list of `eqref`s.

Well, worth asking anyway! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the option `showonlyrefs` in the package [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). See §3.2.2 "Showing only referenced tags" in the manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}  

\begin{align}\label{eq:1}
  1+1=2
\end{align}
See \eqref{eq:1}.

\begin{align}\label{eq:2}
  2+2=4
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]