# Get list of unused labels

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a long article (~20 pages) with lots of equations being numbered and stuff. For a good cleanup, I would like to unnumber the unused equations. I am aware I can [hide the unused numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/how-do-i-number-equations-only-if-they-are-referred-to-in-the-text), but I would like to clean the thing up and not rely to the feature of `mathtools`. Therefore, is it possible to somehow display the list of unused labels?

On the following MWE, it should show (in the log, in bash, whatever) that `boo` was unused:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{BLA}\label{bla}
\section{BOO}\label{boo}
In Section~\ref{bla}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about compatibility with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: You could grep the defined labels from the text and match them to the list of the used references. The gap between both lists is the list of unused references.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen This is possible for `\bibitem ... \cite` since that information is in `aux`, and it's a one-liner in bash. However, `\ref` keeps no trace in `aux`...

Comment: @Werner I'm willing to switch of `hyperref` for those 5 minutes needed for the cleanup ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`refcheck` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcheck):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\begin{document}
\section{BLA}\label{bla}
\section{BOO}\label{boo}
In Section~\ref{bla}.
\end{document}
```

Unused `\label`s are also marked in the `.log`. The above MWE outputs

```
Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `boo' on input line 5.
```

in the `.log`. The visual queues in the output can be turned on/off using the `[norefs]` option. It would also work for `\cite`s (with the accompanying `showcites`/`nocites` boolean package option).

Comment: After discovered this package I asked myself: is there something impossible to do in TeX? Maybe no.

Comment: @Sigur [Yes.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70901/typesetting-limitations-of-latex)

Comment: I think it's important to mention that `refcheck` should be loaded *after* some other package is loaded. I tried to use it in my project by loading it as the very first package, but it didn't work. I then decided to load it last and now it works. I don't know what package(s) should be loaded *before* `refcheck`, but I'm certain there must be some such package.

Answer (score 1):

A homegrown version.  It redefines `\label` and `\ref` and then use `\unusedlabels` at the end to see which labels are unused.  Once the process is done, you can remove the redefinitions.

`\label` is redefined to make a concatenated space-separated string of all the labels.

`\ref` is redefined to go through the concatenated list, item by item, and compare the item to the `\ref` argument, and proceeds to rebuild the concatenated list. If the compare is true, it does nothing, thereby removing the item from the list.  If the compare is false, it adds the item back onto the reconstituted list.

Anything left on the list at the end is unused.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\svlabel\label
\let\svref\ref
\def\unusedlabels{}
\renewcommand\label[1]{\svlabel{#1}\global\edef\unusedlabels{\unusedlabels$<$#1$>$ }}
\renewcommand\ref[1]{\svref{#1}%
  \edef\teststring{$<$#1$>$}%
  \edef\tmp{\unusedlabels}%
  \def\unusedlabels{}%
  \expandafter\refhelper\tmp\relax%
}
\def\refhelper#1 #2\relax{%
  \edef\expandcase{#1}%
  \ifdefstrequal{\teststring}{\expandcase}{}{\edef\unusedlabels{\unusedlabels#1 }}%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else\refhelper#2\relax\fi
}

\begin{document}
\section{BLA}\label{bla}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:first}
y=x
\end{equation}
\section{BOO}\label{boo}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:second}
y=x^2
\end{equation}
In Section~\ref{bla}, I use equation \ref{eq:first}.

Unused labels are \unusedlabels
\end{document}
```

[image]