# equation with auto numbering

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

In LaTeX, when I need to create an equation without a number, I write

```
\[ x=y \]
```

(or using `equation*`) and when I need an equation with a number/label I do

```
\begin{equation}
    x=y \label{eq:myeq}
\end{equation}
```

My question is: is there a way to somehow combine both modes, so that only the label is required to have an equation number?

In other words, I want to somehow make it so that writing something like this

```
 \[ x=y \label{eq:myeq} \]
```

produces an equation with a number and a label, but writing `\[ x=y \]` still produces just an equation. This seems to me to be a more elegant way of doing things.

Comment: Laziness isn't the best advisor ;-) I think it is possible but it will bite you in the end

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/how-do-i-number-equations-only-if-they-are-referred-to-in-the-text

Comment: I don't particularly advise you to change anything. When you are writing a thesis and you want to rehearse at a certain point with a hypertext reference the `equation` environment **very** helpful. If you mess around with any re-definitions chances are that you will end up with some error. This will be particularly annoying if you are writing a long thesis. You don't want to correct a source code for 30+ pages, do you. Stick with `equation`.

Comment: The point of this method is two fold: the first is laziness, or as I like to call it "code brevity". The second is more significant. Most of the time when writing manuscripts, I would come across an equation that I need to reference and which I used `\[\]` to typeset. Making it reference-able requires not only adding the label, but also changing the environment (the same is true if I had been using `equation*`). Which is both annoying and wasteful. I guess just don't the reason behind the original design requiring two modification to the script to have a label, instead of an obvious one.

Comment: @Tohiko: `\[...\]` is the better LaTeX form of `$$...$$`, which is plain TeX, which does not not know of labels as you want to have them.

Comment: see also https://www.ctan.org/pkg/autonum?lang=en

Comment: @David, that's perfect. Along with Christian's suggestion of using     `\let\[\equation` and `\let\]\endequation` I get the desired effect even with amsmath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend this really, but here's a way for `\[...\]` being the same like `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` (which basically is true anyway, since both environments use `$$...$$` in the end again)

It does not work with `amsmath`, however!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\let\[\equation
\let\]\endequation


\newif\iflabelused

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\[}{\global\labelusedfalse}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\label}{\global\labelusedtrue}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\]}{%
  \iflabelused
  \global\labelusedfalse%
  \else
  \let\eqno\relax
  \let\@eqnnum\relax
  \global\labelusedfalse
  \addtocounter{equation}{-1}% Correct the value of the equation counter!
  \fi
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ 
E = mc^{2} \label{foo}
\]

\[ 
E^{2} = (mc^{2})^{2} + (pc)^{2} 
\]


\[ 
E = mc^{2} \label{fooagain}
\]

\[ 
E^{2} = (mc^{2})^{2} + (pc)^{2} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shame that it doesn't work with amsmath, but this looks very interesting. I thought using `\notag` instead of playing with counters might fix it, but it doesn't it. I will try to play around with this code. Thanks!

Comment: @Tohiko: I'll try to fix it for `amsmath`...