# Can we remove equation number that we did not use automatically?

Tags: equations, number

In LaTeX , can we remove equation number that we did not use in a paper automatically?

Comment: Welcome to the TEX.SE. The answer is yes: you will use * in `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`.

Comment: You can try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4729/

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "did not use in a paper". Does creating a cross-reference via `\ref` or `\eqref` count as a use?

Comment: Thank you Torbjørn T. I used what you suggested  `\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}`, and it works. But some equations numbers that I need disperse.  I used `\eqerf` .

Comment: The equations number that disperse belong to \begin{eqnarray} not \begin{equation}.

Comment: Well you shouldn't use `eqnarray` in the first place (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/), switch to using `align` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much.