# get rid of the number of nonreferred equations

Tags: equations, numbering, align

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to organize labels when there are too many equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/how-to-organize-labels-when-there-are-too-many-equations)
>   [How do I number equations only if they are referred to in the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/how-do-i-number-equations-only-if-they-are-referred-to-in-the-text)

I have a lot of equations in my documents and I would like to get rid of the numbering for the ones that are not referred, is there a way to do that or I need to do it manually?
I used the commands `\begin{equation}` and `\begin{align}` for most of them. thanks

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55206/showonlyrefs-and-cleveref

Comment: Please see: [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15820/suppress-equation-number-when-not-refered-to) Can you please confirm if this answers your question?

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/how-to-organize-labels-when-there-are-too-many-equations

Comment: And see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/how-do-i-number-equations-only-if-they-are-referred-to-in-the-text

Comment: @KannappanSampath yes, thanks perfect. Thanks to all